# What classifies as an ultralight vehicle?

Tags: faa-regulations, ultralight, pilot-certification

I am looking into the possibly of getting my pilots license and I noticed that it says you don't need a license for "ultralight vehicles".

What are ultralight vehicles?

I am located in the USA, and I am particularly interested in details for the states Utah and Washington.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Aviation.SE.  What country are you asking about?  The definition varies, as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation).

Comment: Just because you don't need one doesn't mean you shouldn't get one. Jumping into an ultralight without training is a good way to remove yourself from the gene pool.

Answer (score 6):

A typical ultralight looks like this, although there are plenty of different designs:

[image]

<sub>[Source: wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quik_gt450_ultralight_g-gttp_arp.jpg)</sub>

Ultralights in the US are defined and regulated by [14 CFR 103](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr103_main_02.tpl). The definition in 103.1 is:

> For the purposes of this part, an ultralight vehicle is a vehicle
>   that:
>
> (a) Is used or intended to be used for manned operation in the air by
>   a single occupant;
>
> (b) Is used or intended to be used for recreation or sport purposes
>   only;
>
> (c) Does not have any U.S. or foreign airworthiness certificate; and
>
> (d) If unpowered, weighs less than 155 pounds; or
>
> (e) If powered:
>
> (1) Weighs less than 254 pounds empty weight, excluding floats and
>   safety devices which are intended for deployment in a potentially
>   catastrophic situation;
>
> (2) Has a fuel capacity not exceeding 5 U.S. gallons;
>
> (3) Is not capable of more than 55 knots calibrated airspeed at full
>   power in level flight; and
>
> (4) Has a power-off stall speed which does not exceed 24 knots
>   calibrated airspeed.

And 103.7(b) says:

> (b) Notwithstanding any other section pertaining to airman
>   certification, operators of ultralight vehicles are not required to
>   meet any aeronautical knowledge, age, or experience requirements to
>   operate those vehicles or to have airman or medical certificates.

But, just because you can fly an ultralight without any license or training doesn't mean it's a good idea! You should definitely look into local ultralight clubs to help get you started safely. For example, the EAA has a lot of members who fly (and sometimes build) ultralights and they have some [useful information on getting started](https://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aviation-communities-and-interests/ultralights-and-ultralight-aircraft/getting-started-in-ultralight-flying).