# What to do to maintain my Spanish ULM (GA) gyroplane licence valid in the USA when moving there?

Tags: general-aviation, pilots, ultralight, pilot-certification

I have an ultralight gyroplane (GA) Spanish license. What sort of conversion or validation process do I need to follow to be able to continue flying after moving to the USA?

Comment: I suggest you should join the Rotary Wing Forum and ask there... Several members are gyro CFIs in the USA...

Comment: Do you mean a) you want to keep your Spanish license valid while living in the US, or b) you want to use your Spanish license to fly in the US? I have no idea about (a) because it depends on EASA/Spanish regulations, but for (b) you can check [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/62)

Comment: @Pondlife: It could be my edit which is ambiguous. "*after moving to the USA*" means when I'll be in the US, will I be authorized to fly with my Spanish license, if not what should I do?

Comment: @mins Ah, I didn't look at the edit history. In that case I'd say it's a dupe of the other question I linked in my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have a European EASA license - what do I need to do to be allowed to fly in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/183/i-have-a-european-easa-license-what-do-i-need-to-do-to-be-allowed-to-fly-in-th)

Comment: @Pondlife: I wonder if ULM (is that the correct term in the US?) licenses are managed the same way, at EASA level, (typically in France I understand there is no examiner, only an instructor, and no medical exam with an accredited doctor, only a GP paper).

Comment: In Spain, in order to obtain a ULM gyro license, (I have one...) you need to pass an official examination and also a medical type II.

Comment: @mins Good point! I don't know if a ULM license is enough to get an FAA foreign-based license. I gave an answer that covers both cases (I think). VtC retracted.

Answer (score 1):

As a caveat here, I know nothing about gyroplanes. But based on the US regulations it looks like there are a few different possibilities.

If your ULM license is equivalent to an ICAO private license then you could get an FAA foreign-based private license as described [in this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/183/62). I believe you would get category rotorcraft and class gyroplane (see [14 CFR 61.5](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_15)) but I'm not completely sure.

If your ULM license is *not* equivalent to an ICAO private license then it depends on the type of gyroplane you want to fly. If it's considered an [ultralight](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38784/62) then you don't need any license at all. If it's [an LSA](https://www.eaa.org/en/eaa/aviation-communities-and-interests/light-sport-aircraft) then you would need a sport or recreational pilot license. If it's a 'regular' gyroplane, you would need a private license.

If you do need to get an FAA license (sport, recreational or private) you should be able to [use time you logged in Spain to count towards it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/154/62).

Comment: In Spain, an ultralight gyro is a machine with a MTOW of 450 kg. A few kilos more in some European jurisdictions.